# How to pass variables from layout to page in Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I try to create a global variable in layout and call it in pages

E.g:

```
<!-- _layouts/post.html -->
{% assign filename = page.url | split: '/' | last | replace: '.html', '' %}
{{ content }}
```

in post page:

```
<!-- SomePage.html -->
<h1>Page Name: {{ filename }}</h1> //-> # Page Name: SomePage
```

The page name should be printed but I do not know how to do it

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what is the use case you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus I am trying to write the filename automatically pages , just call variable

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are misusing Jekyll as it is not suppose to work like that. It should be used other way around. Templates are designed to show pages with variables, so that you follow many to one relation pages in templates.

The idea is to put repetitive part of your pages in your layout. So you should have your layout defined like this:

```
<!-- _layouts/post.html -->
{% assign filename = page.url | split: '/' | last | replace: '.html', '' %}
<h1>{{ filename }}</h1>
{{ content }}
```

Then you don't have to write that part in your every page, but it is handled automatically for you.